# Sort an object by key names specified in an array

Tags: javascript

I have an object with simple key value pairs and an array with just key names. I would like to sort the objects keys by the order of the keys in the array.

A simplified example:

```
const obj = {
"bread": 11,
"butter": 6,
"milk": 40,
}

const orderedKeys = ["milk", "butter", "bread"]

const expectedResult = {
"milk": 40,
"butter": 6,
"bread": 11,
}
```

In this example I know the amount of keys in both the array and the object, however in reality I don't know the amount and in reality the object can also have more keys than specified in the array. In this case I just want the unknown keys at the end of the object.

What would be the cleanest way to solve this problem?

Answer (score 2):

You can take advantage of [`Array.prototype.reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce) which allow to perform different manipulation on array and return another kind of object or array

```js
const obj = {
"bread": 11,
"butter": 6,
"milk": 40,
}

const orderedKeys = ["milk", "butter", "bread"]

const expectedResult = orderedKeys.reduce((accumulator, current) => {
   return {...accumulator, [current]: obj[current]};

}, {})

console.log(expectedResult);
```

If you want to add key which aren't present in the `orderedKey` but are present inside of the `obj` you can perform it like this

```js
const obj = {
    "bread": 11,
    "butter": 6,
    "milk": 40,
    "cheese": 5
}

const orderedKeys = ["milk", "butter", "bread"]

let expectedResult = orderedKeys.reduce((accumulator, current) => {
    return {...accumulator, [current]: obj[current]};
}, {});

expectedResult = Object.assign({}, expectedResult, obj);
console.log(expectedResult);
```

Answer (score 1):

The simplest way is probably this:

1. `map` the ordered keys to `[key, value]` tuples
2. Reconstruct the object from those using `Object.fromEntries`
3. `...spread` the remaining object properties

```js
const obj = {
    unknown: 15,
    bread: 11,
    butter: 6,
    milk: 40,
}

const orderedKeys = ['milk', 'butter', 'bread']

const orderedObj = {
    ...Object.fromEntries(orderedKeys.map(k => [k, obj[k]])),
    ...obj,
}

console.log(orderedObj)
```

*However*, relying on the order of keys in an object is generally a bad idea, because JavaScript objects are typically considered to be unordered (`{ a: 1, b: 2 }` is usually considered equivalent to `{ b: 2, a: 1 }`). Whether or not they're ordered in practice depends somewhat on implementation. For this reason, and depending on your use case, you could consider using a [`Map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map) instead:

```js
new Map(orderedObj)
```